# Grouping records in mysql query gives error

Tags: mysql

I have a query that should read the records in `leave_requests_2014` table and do a `sum()` of the accepted leave requests of all records for each employe!

```
SELECT lr.emp_id employee,
ifnull(MAX(CASE WHEN lr.leave_type =2 THEN (sum((TO_DAYS(lr.end_date) - TO_DAYS(lr.start_date)+1))) END ) ,0) annual_leave,
ifnull(MAX(CASE WHEN lr.leave_type =3 THEN (sum((TO_DAYS(lr.end_date) - TO_DAYS(lr.start_date)+1))) END ),0) sick_leave
FROM leave_requests_2014 lr
WHERE lr.status =5
GROUP BY lr.emp_id
```

The query that returns the following error:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

I really do not know what should be grouped to get the desired output!

Please have a look at [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a0f) This is the result I actually need

```
employee    annual_leave    sick_leave
   5             7              2
   6             4              1
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you put the `SUM()` function in the wrong place. Move it around `IFNULL` and everything and the query will run. I cannot tell if it will produce the results you expect. Please update the question with table definition, some input data and the output you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Group by" functions such as MAX() and/or SUM() cannot be performed recursively within the same statement. A solution would be to perform the first aggregation in a sub-query. For example:

```
SELECT employee, 
ifnull(MAX(CASE WHEN leave_type =2 THEN annual_leave END),0) annual_leave,
ifnull(MAX(CASE WHEN leave_type =3 THEN sick_leave END),0) sick_leave
FROM
    (
        SELECT lr.emp_id employee, lr.leave_type 
        (CASE WHEN lr.leave_type =2 THEN (sum((TO_DAYS(lr.end_date) - TO_DAYS(lr.start_date)+1))) END ) annual_leave,
        (CASE WHEN lr.leave_type =3 THEN (sum((TO_DAYS(lr.end_date) - TO_DAYS(lr.start_date)+1))) END ) sick_leave
        FROM leave_requests_2014 lr
        WHERE lr.status =5
        GROUP BY lr.emp_id, lr.leave_type
    ) firstAggregation
group by employee
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sergio! You did really help!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (and correct) version of your query:

```
SELECT lr.emp_id AS employee,
   SUM(IF(lr.leave_type = 2, DATEDIFF(lr.end_date, lr.start_date) + 1, 0)) AS annual_leave,
   SUM(IF(lr.leave_type = 3, DATEDIFF(lr.end_date, lr.start_date) + 1, 0)) AS sick_leave,
FROM leave_requests_2014 lr
WHERE lr.status = 5
GROUP BY lr.emp_id
```

Another version, even much simpler that produces the annual leave and the sick leave days on different rows (if needed):

```
SELECT lr.emp_id AS employee, lr.leave_type,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(lr.end_date, lr.start_date) + 1) AS leave_days,
FROM leave_requests_2014 lr
WHERE lr.status = 5 AND lr.leave_type IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY lr.emp_id, lr.leave_type
```

This one needs a little bit of processing on the client code: check the value of `leave_type` to know if the value in `leave_days` is an "annual_leave" or a "sick_leave". Use `0` for the number of days for the other type of leave if it not returned by the query

Comment: Thank you axiac, I really do not want the number of leaves of each employ come in different rows!

Comment: Did you try the first query?